# Done installation of Xampp on drive D , is there a problem

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I have just done installation of my Xampp on my D drive so that I can save space on drive C, so my worry is  will this cause problems now or in the future? Because I've heard some say that It's a mistake.. but to me it seems to be working well. I need some clarification please

Comment: For the record I haven't used it for a long time

Comment: There is no official recommended drive for XAMPP installation. You can install it on D:\. Just ensure that it is in the root folder like **D:\xampp** instead of something like **D:\Program Files\xampp** to avoid any possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

The only time it would matter what drive you installed XAMPP on is if it is a removable drive. So if D:\ is a 'regular' hard drive partition, you should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

No problem to install xampp in your D:\xampp it works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).